# Returning nightmare with .map() inside of a .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've been at this for a while. So I have some nested navigation json that I am using. The top level navigation is loading fine (the nav.map) once I move further down the rabbit hole I find myself not returning the top level or the sub level navigation. Everything compiles successfully. Am I just missing it?

```
return(
 <List component="nav" className={classes.root}>
   {nav.map(function(element) {
     <ListItem
       button
       onClick={handleClick}
       id={element.toplevel}
       key={element.toplevel}
     >
       <ListItemText primary={element.toplevel} />
       {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
     </ListItem>;
     return element.children.map(function(child) {
       return (
         <Collapse timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
           <List component="div" disablePadding>
             <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
               <ListItemIcon>
                 <StarBorder />
               </ListItemIcon>
               <ListItemText primary={child.name} />
             </ListItem>
           </List>
         </Collapse>
       );
     });
   })}
 </List>
);
```

Comment: Be careful of your semi-colons. I don't think they can go into react javascript expressions. Also you're not returning the first list item, only the element children map.

Comment: wrap your second map in curly braces too and no need to return that.

Comment: The `<ListItem` that comes before the `return` in the code you've shared is a no-op. It doesn't actually do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your map callback functions actually return the jsx code. Your return statements are not set right.

One way that is commonly used in react-land to make the jsx code more readable is the arrow function syntax. This way you get rid of the return statements and return the whole function body (it's just syntactic sugar).

Next thing: be aware of your closing tags. I just assumed that your list item of the element object closes after the ListItemText tag and that your second map function opens a new list item after your element ListItem. jsx only lets you return one root tag at a time. This is why (as the comment below has suggested) using an empty `<> ... </>` tag pair as a root element will solve this issue.

```
return (
    <List component="nav" className={classes.root}>
      {data.nav.map((element) => (
        <>
        <ListItem
          button
          onClick={handleClick}
          id={element.toplevel}
          key={element.toplevel}
        >
          <ListItemText primary={element.toplevel} />
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
        {
          element.children.map((child) => (
              <Collapse timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <List component="div" disablePadding>
                  <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                      <StarBorder />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={child.name} />
                  </ListItem>
                </List>
              </Collapse>
          ))
        }
      </>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
```

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-uv7c7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You should wrap the first return value with `<>...</>` because it won't work as is.

Comment: yeah very true, but I am actually thinking he forgot the closing tag for <ListItem> instead

Comment: Unfortunately, vscode dims the rest of the code when the second .map() starts and it does not show the component in dev tools.I have posted some code here. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-srqnq

Comment: Yes, that seems more likely, it will work this way but you'll have to remove the 
old `</ListItem>` because it is still there, there are two close tags for the top level `ListItem`.

Comment: I completely overlook that one. Added link to updated sandbox and integrated the empty root tags.

Comment: This worked! I changed some of the state hooks to be static values and we are good to go! Thanks guys!

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-l0nvn

Comment: Also, is the <> (fragment) required when returning multiple components?

Comment: <> is again just syntactic sugar. It will not create any html tag but allows you to bundle multiple components. You could also use <div> or any other html tag instead but those would be rendered to the DOM. :) You also have to have only one root component though!

Comment: Just not sure why the demo at https://material-ui.com/components/lists/ does not require this `<>` sorry for questions just trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, i have restructured it a bit.

```
 <List component="nav" className={classes.root}>
   {nav.map(function(element) {
     return(
     <ListItem
       button
       onClick={handleClick}
       id={element.toplevel}
       key={element.toplevel}
     >
       <ListItemText primary={element.toplevel} />
       {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
     </ListItem>
     {element.children.map(function(child) {
       return (
         <Collapse timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
           <List component="div" disablePadding>
             <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
               <ListItemIcon>
                 <StarBorder />
               </ListItemIcon>
               <ListItemText primary={child.name} />
             </ListItem>
           </List>
         </Collapse>
       )
     })
    }
   }))}
 </List>
);
```